# Contextual Filters not working

Tags: views

I have a view which is a clone of the Product view (created for the Drupal commerce module).

In the view I set a contextual filter. But it just doesn't work as required.

It is very rare since the view is pretty simple.

Please take a look at the capture I've made:
 http://screencast.com/t/tgRPQQCm

The "Categoria" field is a **Term Reference** field type.

If I use other field as a Contextual Filter it works fine. Look: http://screencast.com/t/yspxMFxjA0k

Then there is something wrong with the field??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to this. It was missing some setting in "When the value IS in the url..."

Check the image capture:

http://screencast.com/t/6dY8k3z4Za

Comment: Please update the image. Upload the images via WYSIWYG

Answer (score 0):

I do not have sound so not sure if I was following properly, but could it be that you are using a contextual filter rather than a regular filter?

Comment: I need it to be a Contextual Filter because I will provide the argument in the url. Sorry for the audio, I had the mic off...

Comment: i just added a new capture to show that if use other field then the Contextual filter works just fine.